# Merge php duplicate data array

Tags: php

I want to make a table like the attachment, can someone help me? I'm confused on how to make the table look like the image, can I remove the second data if inside the array there are some duplicate values?

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: Final Result]

This is how my code looks like:

```php
<?php

$init_array = array(
    array('kode_pemesanan'=>'FPS26122018001', 
        'nama'=>'bintang', 
        'value1'=>'A Pieu pastel blusher (Shade 1)', 
        'value2'=>'1', 
        'value3'=>'50000', 
        'value4'=> '9000',
        'value5'=> '59000',
    ),
    array('kode_pemesanan'=>'FPS26122018001', 
        'nama'=>'bintang', 
        'value1'=>'A Pieu pastel blusher (Shade 3)', 
        'value2'=>'1', 
        'value3'=>'10000', 
        'value4'=> '9000',
        'value5'=> '59000',
    ),
    array('kode_pemesanan'=>'FPS26122018002', 
        'nama'=>'bintang', 
        'value1'=>'A Pieu pastel blusher (Shade 3)', 
        'value2'=>'1', 
        'value3'=>'10000', 
        'value4'=> '9000',
        'value5'=> '59000',
    ),
);

$formatted_array = array();

foreach($init_array as $element){
    $formatted_array[$element['kode_pemesanan']][] = $element;
}
?>

<table border='2' width="70%" align="center">
 <? foreach($formatted_array as $row ): ?>
   <tr>
     <td rowspan="<?=count($row)?>"><?=$row[0]['kode_pemesanan']?></td>
     <td rowspan="<?=count($row)?>"><?=$row[0]['nama']?></td>
     <? foreach( $row as $value ): ?>
      <td><?=$value['value1']?></td>
      <td><?=$value['value2']?></td>
      <td><?=$value['value3']?></td>
      <td><?=$value['value4']?></td>
      <td><?=$value['value5']?></td>
      </tr><tr>
     <? endforeach; ?>
   </tr>
 <? endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try `array_unique()`

```
print_r(array_unique($init_array));
```

So you can try like this. Put this line after your array `$init_array` it will remove all duplicate records.

```
$init_array = array_unique($init_array);
```

Let me know if this is helping you.

Try This Code then

```
<?php
$init_array = array(
array('kode_pemesanan'=>'FPS26122018001', 
    'nama'=>'bintang', 
    'value1'=>'A Pieu pastel blusher (Shade 1)', 
    'value2'=>'1', 
    'value3'=>'50000', 
    'value4'=> '9000',
    'value5'=> '59000',
),
array('kode_pemesanan'=>'FPS26122018001', 
    'nama'=>'bintang', 
    'value1'=>'A Pieu pastel blusher (Shade 3)', 
    'value2'=>'1', 
    'value3'=>'10000', 
    'value4'=> '9000',
    'value5'=> '59000',
),
array('kode_pemesanan'=>'FPS26122018002', 
    'nama'=>'bintang', 
    'value1'=>'A Pieu pastel blusher (Shade 3)', 
    'value2'=>'1', 
    'value3'=>'10000', 
    'value4'=> '9000',
    'value5'=> '59000',
),
);

$formatted_array = array();

foreach($init_array as $element){
$formatted_array[$element['kode_pemesanan']][] = $element;
}
?>

<table border='2' width="70%" align="center">
<?php foreach($formatted_array as $row ): ?>
<tr>
 <td rowspan="<?=count($row)?>"><?=$row[0]['kode_pemesanan']?></td>
 <td rowspan="<?=count($row)?>"><?=$row[0]['nama']?></td>
 <?php foreach( $row as $key => $value ): ?>
  <td><?=$value['value1']?></td>
  <td><?=$value['value2']?></td>
  <td><?=$value['value3']?></td>
  <?php if($key == 0): ?>
  <td rowspan="<?=count($row)?>"><?=$value['value4']?></td>
  <td rowspan="<?=count($row)?>"><?=$value['value5']?></td>
  <?php endif; ?>
  </tr><tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </table>
```

Comment: thank for your help but the result not like the final image output >